# maximum matrix cost path,

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this problem through dynamic programming:

> You are given a matrix of *n* rows and *m* columns. Every element has a number
> and the rabbit staying at the top left element.
>
> Calculate the maximum sum such that the rabbit gets to the bottom element and
> only two moved allowed:
>
> Two steps right and 1 step down (*x*+2, *y*+1);
> Two steps down and 1 step to the right (*x*+1, *y*+2);
>
> **Input:**
>
> The first line contains two naturals *n* and *m* (*1 ≤ n, m ≤ 10<sup>3</sup>*) – the quantity of rows and columns of the matrix.
>
> The next *n* lines contain *m* numbers – the values of the matrix
> elements.
>
> The top left coordinates are (1, 1), the bottom right
> corner’s – (*n*, *m*).
>
> **Output:**
>
> The maximum sum so that the rabbit reaches the bottom right.
> If bottom right can not be reached, output `-`
>
> Input 1:
>
> ```
> 3 3 
> 5 0 0 
> 0 1 2  
> 1 0 1
> ```
>
> Output 1:
>
> ```
> -
> ```
>
> Input 2:
>
> ```
> 4 4
> 5 2 1 0
> 1 0 0 0
> 2 1 3 0
> 0 0 1 7
> ```
>
> Output 2:
>
> ```
> 13
> ```

This the code I tried to develop:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
void findMaxSum(int *a[], int r, int c)
{
    int **res = new int*[r];
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        res[i] = new int[c];
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            res[i][j] = -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < c-1; j++) {
            res[i + 1][j + 2] = max(a[i][j] + a[i + 1][j + 2], res[i + 1][j + 2]);
            res[i + 2][j + 1] = max(a[i][j] + a[i + 2][j + 1], res[i + 2][j + 1]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            cout << res[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    delete[] res;
}

int main() {    
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int r, c;
    cin >> r >> c;
    int **a = new int*[r];
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        a[i] = new int[c];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];
    }
    findMaxSum(a, r, c);
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

Is this the approach, are the calculations inside for loops correct?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Great! Please read that link.

Comment: Your approach is correct; your calculations are not.  I don't want to go into too much detail because this looks like a homework problem, but if you go through Input 2 applying this algorithm by hand, you'll notice that what you're doing isn't what's in the code.

Comment: @dspeyer This is Not a homework problem, but just to practice dynamic programming.

Comment: @dspeyer if you can help with some hints or something it would be much appreciated

Comment: Please provide the link to the where this challenge is posted.

Comment: There is none, I have solved the minimum cost path, it is very famous. I tried to go for this version of maximum thinking of the knight moves. I don t know how to use for loops for such steady jumps to the right places. I have the dynamic approach, it s just how for can be used.

Comment: @trincot I have been stopped to ask any more questions, can you give a positive vote, maybe I ll be able to post more questions.

Comment: I upvoted one question just now, but others need improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First realise that this is a variant of the more [common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361555/minimum-cost-path-in-matrix) where valid "moves" are "right" and "down". It can be mapped to it.

If you visualise the spots that can be reached by valid moves, you get this pattern in the matrix:

```
x - - - - - - - -
- - x - - - - - - 
- x - - x - - - -
- - - x - - x - -
- - x - - x - - x
- - - - x - - x -
- - - x - - x - -
- - - - - x - - x
```

So actually many matrix values don't even play a role -- they cannot be reached. If we also remove the spots from where the *target* cannot be reached, then we get this. I also use some different letters to highlight a property:

```
x - - - - - - - -
- - x - - - - - - 
- y - - x - - - -
- - - y - - x - -
- - z - - y - - -
- - - - z - - y -
- - - - - - z - -
- - - - - - - - z
```

Where it has an "x", the spot can be reached via (+2,+1) type of moves only. Where it has an "y", it needs one (+1,+2) type of move, and where there is a "z", two of those are needed.

This is a shape that can be translated to this shape:

```
x x x x
y y y y 
z z z z
```

It would be interesting to translate the problem like that, and solve it in that configuration.

I will not pursue that idea here.

Your code is currently missing the test for when to output `-`.

We need to test whether the target cell can be reached. You can see that a spot cannot be reached if the sum of its x and y coordinate (when zero-based) is not a multiple of 3. And there are also spots where this sum is a multiple of 3, but which are still out of reach. This is where one of the coordinates is at least the double of the other coordinate (marked with an asterisk):

```
x - - * - - * - -
- - x - - * - - * 
- y - - x - - * -
* - - y - - x - -
- - z - - y - - -
- * - - z - - y -
* - - - - - z - -
- - * - - - - - z
```

So you should add this line to your code:

```
if ((r+c) % 3 != 2 || r*2 < c || c*2 < r) {
    cout << "-";
    return;
}
```

`(r+c) % 3 != 2` is derived from `(r-1 + c-1) % 3 != 0`, and `r*2 < c` is derived from `(r-1)*2 < (c-1)*2` with a difference of 1, which is not relevant given the first condition.

**For the initialisation part:** it is not necessary to initialise the `res` matrix with -1 values. You wouldn't want to involve a -1 in your calculation anyway. You'll want to *avoid* relying on such values. Instead you *must* initialise a starting point for the dynamic programming to work:

```
res[0][0] = a[0][0];
```

**Then, for the actual "bootstrapping":** I would first move with only one type of move, and accumulate the cost in that direction:

```
for (int i = 2, j = 1; (r-i)*2 > c-j; i+=2, j++) {
    res[i][j] = res[i-2][j-1] + a[i][j];
}
```

Note that the loop's stop-condition eliminates spots from where the target would be out of reach.

Do the same in the other direction:

```
for (int i = 1, j = 2; (c-j)*2 > r-i; i++, j+=2) {
    res[i][j] = res[i-1][j-2] + a[i][j];
}
```

Now you have set up the "outer borders" for the main dynamic programming part. The other valid spots will always have 2 possible spots to come from. So take all other paths by choosing the maximum value from the two spots you could come from:

```
for (int i = 2, j = 1; (r-i)*2 > c-j; i+=2, j++) {
    for (int m = i + 1, n = j + 2; (c-n)*2 > r-m; m++, n += 2) {
        res[m][n] = max(res[m-1][n-2], res[m-2][n-1]) + a[m][n];
    }
}
```

And finally output the result:

```
cout << res[r-1][c-1];
```

NB: I would prefer a function to *return* that value, and let `main` do all the I/O.

Comment: The third loop was challenging to understand, but I got it. That's what I had in ind, it's just I didn't know how to incorporate those i and j into a for loop. Thanks

Comment: I am having a difficulty with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59485987/coding-teams-placed-on-the-result-board-based-on-solved-tasks-and-penalty-time

 Can you take a look?

Comment: This challenge actually was provided yesterday by one of our classmates, and we want to solve it, that's it, when there is the source of the challenge, I post it. I have rephrased the question to be more clearer.

Comment: I made it more focused. I am very sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the points to address:

- Out-of-bounds access for array elements.
  Look carefully at which elements you want to access, and what are the loop boundaries.
  The simplest fix is to widen the arrays accordingly.
- Wrong initialization for array elements.
  Note that `-1` (an unreachable square) plus `10` is `9` which looks like a valid value.
  The simplest fix is to initialize with minus-infinity (which is the proper neutral element for the `max` operation) instead of `-1`.
  A good *default* value for minus-infinity is `INT_MIN / 2`.

These two might be sufficient to make the program work.

---

Here are the points to consider for the future:

- Array construction.
  For one, there are not enough `delete` operations for the corresponding `new` operation, so the program leaks memory.
  Having said that, I don't see why would one need the cumbersome memory management of multidimensional plain arrays in C++, when `vector`s do the same with more convenience.
  The minor slowdown associated with `vector`s does not justify suffering from whole classes of bugs in the other 97% of the cases.
- Asking questions.
  The question goes like this: "here is the problem, and here is the solution *in code*".
  The missing step is explaining, in text, what the code is *meant to do*.
  As a result, people not familiar with the problem and the solution will have a hard time actually understanding your question in the first place, and rightfully consider it a question not in proper form.
  Additionally, you may find that addressing that missing step, while looking at your code of course, will answer some questions without any more interaction :) (see [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)).

Comment: Interesting, Thanks!